# Save NSMutableArray in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, save, nsmutablearray

I need to save many NSMutableArray with my custom objects and I want to know what is the best way to do this.

Maybe NSUserDefaults is not the best way to do it.

What should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your array contains *non-plist* objects, [then you cannot use `NSUserDefaults` without first encoding the array.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)**

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

**You'll want to encode it [using `NSKeyedArchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/).** This will give you an `NSData` object that you can then store in `NSUserDefaults`, or write it to file  through `NSKeyedArchiver` itself.

All you have to do is conform to `NSCoding` in your custom object, and override `initWithCoder:` to initialise your object when it's loaded and `encodeWithCoder:` to encode your variables when it gets encoded. For example, your custom object will look something like this:

```
@interface customArrayObject : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic) NSString* foo;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger bar;

@end

@implementation customArrayObject

-(instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder { // decode variables
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _foo = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"foo"];
        _bar = [aDecoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"bar"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder { // encode variables
    [aCoder encodeObject:_foo forKey:@"foo"];
    [aCoder encodeInteger:_bar forKey:@"bar"];
}

@end
```

**It's also worth noting that `NSUserDefaults` is used to store user *preferences***, and therefore if your array contains data that isn't in any way to do with a user preference, you shouldn't be using `NSUserDefaults` - you should be writing it to disk yourself.

Writing your array to disk is actually a lot more trivial than it sounds, you can use the `archiveRootObject:toFile:` method on `NSKeyedArchiver`. For example, this will write your custom array to the documents directory:

```
// Gets the documents directory path
NSString* documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(directory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];

// Archive and save the file to foo.dat in the documents directory. Returns whether the operation was successful.
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:customArray toFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsPath, @"foo.dat"]]
```

**However, it is also worth noting that this flat (yes/no) as to whether the operation was successful isn't that great when it comes to error handling.** If you want to implement custom error handling, then you'll want to first encode the object using `NSKeyedArchiver`'s `archivedDataWithRootObject:` method, and then `NSData`'s `writeToFile:options:error:` method.

Comment: `NSKeyedArchiver` has a method for archiving directly to a file, so you might as well use that rather than converting it to data and then writing to the file in a separate call.

Comment: so it does! never seen that before... I'll update my answer in a sec. Although, personally I'd still prefer to use the `NSData` approach as it has much more scope for error handling. `NSKeyedArchiver` just returns a flat yes or no to whether it worked.

Comment: Thats true, though `writeToFile:atomically` also just returns yes/no. Use `writeToFile:options:error:` if you want more specific error info.

Comment: @dan yes, I was only using that in the answer for simplicity sake ;)

Comment: The objects handled automatically are not "non-custom", but called plist (objects). There are tons of Apple made classes that cannot be handled by `NSUserDefault`. (The reason ist, that the file representation of user defaults are an XML plist.)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad oops! thanks for pointing out, I've edited the answer.